# How to create popup user control wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controls

I want to create a `datagrid` with `popup` cell.I use below code in windows form and it is working fine.
But I want it to convert it to a user control. Please help how to do this.

XAML

```
   private void Dgv_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
            Point newPosition = new Point();
            double rowX = 0;
            DataGrid dg = GetRowsDataGrid(e.Row);
            if (dg != null)
            {
                rowX = GetColumnXPosition(e.Column, dg);
                newPosition = e.Row.TranslatePoint(new  Point(Dgv.RowHeaderWidth, e.Row.ActualHeight), this);
            }

            if (newPosition != new Point())
            {
                Popup1.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(rowX + Dgv.RowHeaderActualWidth, newPosition.Y - Dgv.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
            }
            Popup1.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private double GetColumnXPosition(DataGridColumn column, DataGrid grid)
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        if (grid == null)
            return result;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridColumn dgc = grid.Columns[i];
            if (dgc.Equals(column))
                break;
            result += dgc.ActualWidth;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private DataGrid GetRowsDataGrid(DataGridRow row)
    {
        DependencyObject result = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(row);
        while (result != null && !(result is DataGrid))
        {
            result = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(result);
        }
        return result as DataGrid;
    }
    private void Dgv_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup1.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

I want to convert this to user control using below code
XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Class="WpfGrid.WGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfGrid"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" Width="500" PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" BeginningEdit="DataGrid_BeginningEdit" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" PreviewTextInput="DataGrid_PreviewTextInput">
<DataGrid.Resources >
    <Popup x:Key="GPopup" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="XPopup" PopupAnimation="Slide"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=WGrid}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Height="150" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

In code

```
      private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Point newPosition = new Point();
            double rowX = 0;
            DataGrid dg = GetRowsDataGrid(e.Row);
            if (dg != null)
            {
                rowX = GetColumnXPosition(e.Column, dg); 
                newPosition = e.Row.TranslatePoint(new Point(Dgv.RowHeaderWidth, e.Row.ActualHeight), this); 
            }

            if (newPosition != new Point())
            {
               **//Upto this it is ok  here I want to access the      <DataGrid.Resources > Gpopup and show it.**
                Popup1.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(rowX + Dgv.RowHeaderActualWidth, newPosition.Y - Dgv.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
            }
            Popup1.IsOpen = true;


    }
```

I don't know weather I am right as I am new to Wpf so please help how to acheive this or is there any alternate to create user control
to popup window below a cell.
Thanks

Comment: If I understand u correctly, you want to edit a cell in a popup. ie; when u double click a cell, that cell should appear in a popup ?

Comment: Yes When I am editing I want to show something in below popup window

Comment: I saw ur code, it is fine, not sure about funcationality. what problem r u facing ?

Comment: there is no problem  i want to create a user control using this code

Comment: That is already a user control. Save your DataGrid xaml file as MyDataGrid.xaml and use it like u use a usercontrol.